# How to encode NSData raw bytes directly to UTF-16 (Unicode)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, encoding, nsdata

Environment: iOS Xcode Objective-C Garbled Unicode UTF-16

My Question:

I got the file content from a remote file and then stored it into NSData object, then I want to convert the NSData to Unicode encoding (note: not UTF-8,UTF-16 will okay), the problem is that I do not know the original file content encoding, what can I do to convert the unknown raw bytes into Unicode (UTF-16)?

I have tried so many method, but no one successfully touch my target, the code:

```
NSData *chunk = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString* newStr = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:chunk encoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding]  autorelease];
NSData* d = [newStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
[d writeToFile:newFilePath atomically:YES];
```

got the file into NSData, encode it into Unicode and write to file.

```
NSString*  converted_str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:chunk encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData * d = [(id)CFStringCreateExternalRepresentation(NULL, (CFStringRef)converted_str, kCFStringEncodingUnicode, 0) autorelease];
[d writeToFile:newFilePath atomically:YES];
```

convert the NSData to NSString, then restore it into NSData for write to file, not work.

```
[converted_str writeToFile:newFilePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:&error];
```

write to file directly using NSString object, garbled.

```
CFStringRef converted_str = CFStringCreateWithBytes(NULL, [chunk  bytes],[chunk length], kCFStringEncodingUTF8,false);  
CFStringRef newStr = [chunk dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData * d = [(id)CFStringCreateExternalRepresentation(NULL, (CFStringRef)big5Str, NSUnicodeStringEncoding, 0) autorelease];
[d writeToFile:newFilePath atomically:YES];
```

Using cString to do the encoding work, but also failure.

```
char converted[([chunk length] + 1)];
[chunk getCString:converted maxLength:([chunk length] + 1) encoding: NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"converted:%s", converted);
NSString *converted_str = [NSString stringWithCString:converted encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"converted_str:%@", converted_str);
```

I also using usedEncoding:&xxx to get the original file encoding, then try to decode it into string object using the returned encoding, ..., failure again.

```
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSString *chunk = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[rb fileURL] usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
...
```

I then try to using kCFStringEncodingUTF16 to get the Unicode encoded buffer, but failure.

```
NSStringEncoding encode = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingUTF16);
NSString *chunk = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:encode error:&error];
```

In the end, I want to try libiconv for iOS( iPhone,iPad), but the trouble is the encoding of source content is unknown, the usedEncoding:&xxx function can not always work.

I have no idea of this trouble ... :(

Is there someone meet the similar question, please give me some direction, any answer will be most appreciated , thank you.

Sincerely wishing you and your family happiness and health.

Comment: answer the question of myself, I use uchardet (http://code.google.com/p/uchardet) to do the work and it work stable. Hope this info is useful and can help others.